# Complex secondary index operations

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I can create a secondary index for this table:

```
{
  contact: [
    'example@example.com'
  ]
}
```

Like this: `indexCreate('contact', {multi: true})`

But can I create index for this:

```
{
  contact: [
    {
      type: 'email',
      main: true
      value: 'andros705@gmail.com'
    }
    {
      type: 'phone'
      value: '0735521632'
    }
  ]
}
```

Secondary index would only search in objects whose type is 'email' and main is set to 'true'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you might create such an index:

```
table.indexCreate(
  'email',
  row => row('contact').filter({type: 'email'})('value'),
  {multi: true})
```

This works by using a multi-index. When the `multi: true` argument is passed to `indexCreate`, the index function is expected to return an array instead of a single value. Every element in that array can be used to look up the document in the index (using `getAll` or `between`). If the array is empty, the document will not show up in the index.

Comment: Genius 0>0
Thanks, this helps.
I think we've met on Slack :P